# Chef with omnibus using 3rd party gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, gitlab-omnibus

Could someone please help with a question regarding use of a 3rd party gem with an omnibus installation running Chef recipes?
I would like to use a 'p4ruby' gem that has been packaged up with omnibus and should be available for use in a recipe using

```
require 'P4'
```

I get the error

```
cannot load such file -- P4
```

In the installation directory I can see

```
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubyconf.h
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubydebug.h
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/cache/p4ruby-2015.1.0.gem
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/specifications/p4ruby-2015.1.0.gemspec
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/build_info/p4ruby-2015.1.0.info
./embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubyconf.h
./embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubydebug.h
./embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/p4ruby-2015.1.0.gem
```

I have read through the Chef docs and see that I could use *chef_gem* or *gem_package* for example

```
gem_package 'p4ruby' do
end
```

However this always tries to compile the gem and this leads to errors in our target installation environment as we cannot expect dev tools such as *make* and *g++* to be available and we do not want to force installation of them.

How can I get Chef to 'see' this gem or to specifiy a 3rd party gem without compilation running? Is this possible?

For further info if I do use *gem_package* on a machine that does have *make* and *g++* I end up with the following in the install directory (which looks slightly different than before). Is this a path issue?? I've searched all over but cannot find a solution

```
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubyconf.h
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubydebug.h
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/cache/p4ruby-2015.1.0.gem
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/specifications/p4ruby-2015.1.0.gemspec
./embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/build_info/p4ruby-2015.1.0.info
./embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubyconf.h
./embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/p4ruby-2015.1.0/ext/P4/p4rubydebug.h
./embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/p4ruby-2015.1.0.gem
./embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/specifications/p4ruby-2015.1.0.gemspec
```

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get Chef to 'see' this gem or to specifiy a 3rd party gem
>   without compilation running? Is this possible?

No, if a gem has some `C` extension, it must be compiled and will need build tools, that's why there's the [build-essential](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/build-essential) cookbook.

The differences between `chef_gem` and `gem_package` are this:

- `gem_package` will install to system ruby (or default to chef embedded ruby is none present) where `chef_gem` will always install in chef embedded ruby.
- `gem_package` run in converge phase where `chef_gem` run at compile time

The main reason is that `chef_gem` is aimed at installing gem to be used in recipes where `gem_package` is aimed at managing system gems for use out of chef.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a way of doing this...

```
$:.unshift *Dir[File.path('<my_path_to_gems>/**/lib')]
```

I can then

```
require 'P4'
```

in my recipes